# Docker does not enforce apparmor profile

Tags: docker, apparmor

I am trying to confine my docker containers with Apparmor. Apparmor is working on my machine and several profiles are already enforced.

The [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/) state:

`Docker automatically generates and loads a default profile for  containers named docker-default`

After starting my container with

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti $ID
```

I expected aa-status to display the docker-default profile, but that was not the case.

I tried setting `--security-opt apparmor:docker-default` and `--security-opt apparmor:my-own-profile`, which still resulted in unconfined running containers.

`cat /proc/$CONTAINER_PID/attr/current` resulted in `unconfined`

I reinstalled Docker, rebooted. Same problem.

I reinstalled Apparmor, rebooted. Same problem

I am runing Docker version 18.06.1-ce on Manjaro

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?